# Twitter bootstrap themes in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, railscasts

Im setting up a rails app using the ["bootstrap-sass"](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) version for rails.

In following the railcast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics) im attempting to run:

```
rails g bootstrap:themed products -f
```

But getting a generator not found error.. I was wondering if these types of generators and bootstrap "themes" are only compatible with the main version of the gem `(gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails')`

Comment: You know you can just run `rails g` to see what generators are available?

Comment: Also, this is the kind of question that can be easily solved by looking at the documentation.

Comment: its not covered in the documentation for that version of the gem and yes, i know i can run rails g.

Comment: Then what are you asking? `rails g` will tell you what generators are available, there's no need to ask it here.

Comment: I think your confusion may be caused by thinking they are different versions of the same gem - I can't see any evidence of that from the Github repo, I think they're independent so there's nothing to say functionality from one will be in the other.

Comment: They are independent, its a different version of bootstrap. Im asking if themes are compatible with this version. Thanks, but this question is more aimed at someone who knows bootstrap well.

Comment: I'm sorry if my comments came across as aggressive, they weren't intended to. I do know bootstrap well, I use twitter-bootstrap-rails. However please note that answering this question requires zero knowledge of bootstrap and only basic knowledge of rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they can't be used.  It's a different gem altogether.  Cracking it open, the bootstrap-sass gem doesn't appear to have any generators in it.